# d3 wrongly append dom elements on data update

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, graph

I'm tryng to use d3 and his enter/exit pattern to update my bar grap
here you can see the current results
http://jsfiddle.net/k8sftbez/

the idea is that I should have a g elemennt with a rect and a text for every data object attribute, like:

```
<g>
  <rect></rect>
  <text></text>
</g>
```

the graph is created as aspected but my problem is when I try to update the bar color (I do it on mouseover), instead of updating the currents rect and text tag, it appends 2 new tags on every update.
On the example you can see the problem (http://jsfiddle.net/k8sftbez/)

Comment: You're adding text/rects on every hover, you should only toggle them. see here : http://jsfiddle.net/k8sftbez/1/ : when you hover just over the text the text looks more bold. its because your putting a text layer over another text layer over another text layer on each hover

Comment: yep, this problem what I was triyng to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've fixed modifing the update function like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/5ft6uL6k/

I think is the more elegant way, using the placeholder and update them.

basically this part:

```
var bar = chart.selectAll("g").data(data)
bar.enter().append("g").attr("transform", function(d, i) {
  return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")";
})

var valueBar = bar.append("rect");
valueBar
  .attr(valueBarValues.attr)
  .attr("width", function(d){return x(d.value)})
  .style(valueBarValues.style);

bar.append("text")
  .attr(textConfig.attrs)
  .style(textConfig.style)
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })

bar.exit().remove();
```

is changed like this:

```
    var bar = chart.selectAll("g").data(data)
    var barEnter = bar.enter().append("g");

    barEnter.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")";
    });

    barEnter.append("rect");
    barEnter.append("text");

    var textBar = bar.selectAll("text")
    textBar
        .attr(textConfig.attrs)
        .style(textConfig.style)
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })

    var valueBar = bar.selectAll("rect");
    valueBar
    .attr(valueBarValues.attr)
    .attr("width", function(d){return x(d.value)})
    .style(valueBarValues.style);

  bar.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because your update function actually includes the creation of the bars as well, in order to have them just change the color you should have two separate functions, one for the appending of the objects, and one for the update (for example you could have a function that appends rectangles without any attributes and the update function that styles them)

Comment: I'm really a noob of d3, but as far as I understood, .enter() return just the differences and .remove() should remove the old one.
So I was expecting that update function could work also as init funciton, am I wrong?

Comment: Can you details a little your response?

Comment: let's say you have the part up until the appending of the rectangles in the main thing, then you create a function called updateRect where you select the rectangles and apply the attributes (cx,cy width height and fill or stroke if you need) and then call that function both after the appending and in the event where the rectangles should be changed